# Laravel sync a 3 model pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to sync a 3 model pivot table. This is how I can receive the data from my form.

```php
$data = array(
position_id->   1 => ['user_id' => [5, 14]],
position_id->   2 => ['user_id' => [15]],
position_id->   3 => ['user_id' => [6]],
position_id->   4 => ['user_id' => [5]],
position_id->   6 => ['user_id' => [8, 3, 14]],
position_id->   7 => ['user_id' => [1]],
);
```

This is how I wish to store the data:

```php
$order->crew()->sync($data);
```

This is how the database needs to look after the data is saved:

[image: How database should look]

---

**The problem:**

How can I do this?

Comment: Your data doesn't make much sense to me. For example, what's supposed to happen with the following line? `2 => ['user_id' => [0 => 15]],` It's missing a parameter. Do you allow nulls on position or user_id? Is `$user_id[0]` position or user_id? What about `6 => ['user_id' => [0 => 8, 1 => 3, 2 => 14]],`? There's three parameters there. Which ones are supposed to be which columns?

Comment: @IGP Oh sorry, the keys that range from 1 to 7 are the position_id. I'm not specifying the order_id in the data array because it will be assign when I call the relation $order->crew()->sync($data)

Answer (score 0):

`sync()` won't allow for duplicates. You're gonna have to use `attach()` but first, the `$data` array must be mapped to the proper format (`[position_id => ['user_id' => user_id]]`)

```
collect($data)
    ->map(function($users, $position_id) {
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($users['user_id'] as $user_id) {
            $arr[] = [$position_id => ['user_id' => $user_id]];
        };
        return $arr;
    })
    ->flatten(1)
    ->each(function($position) use ($order) {
        $order->crew()->attach($position);
    });
```

Comment: This works great! The only problem is when I delete data from the array... it doesn't delete the data from the database. I guess this can be solved by comparing the data in the array and the data inside the database and calling the detach method. Is there a way to compare the data and get the difference?